# How to make our npm package(to be published) as small as possible

Tags: webpack, npm-publish

How to minimize the size of our npm package and Do we need to add webpack as dependency when publishing an npm package.
I have referred below article:
https://medium.com/quick-code/publish-your-own-react-component-as-npm-package-under-5-minutes-8a47f0cb92b9

I have published my first npm package. But when we install it from npm package it says 'added 67 packages'. Why 67 packages?

This is the dependency section from package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "webpack": "4.32.2",
    "react-icons": "3.7.0"
  },

Answer (score 1):

You have only 3 dependencies in your package.json. But each of these dependencies contains a lot other dependencies inside.

Let's see how many dependencies (including nested) does your package have:

```
$ npx howfat react@16.8.6 webpack@4.32.2 react-icons@3.7.0
Dependencies: 356
Size: 36.79mb
Files: 3403
```

Why so many, not just 67? Because the project which includes your package has a lot of other dependencies. 67 is just a number of new packages, which were not included before.

In most cases you should not specify webpack as a dependency. You could install it as a dev dependency instead:

`npm install --save-dev webpack`

Webpack is a huge package, so it's too expensive to include it as dependency.